# How to make this destructor virtual

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract, overloading

```
#include "RegionsSingleImage.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

RegionsSingleImage::RegionsSingleImage(std::string fName){
#ifdef __CVLOADIMAGE_WORKING__
  im = cvLoadImage(fName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
#else
  im = readImage(fName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
#endif
  if(im == NULL)
  {
    cerr << "Could not read image from " << fName << endl;
    assert(false);
  }
  list = new std::vector<Region *>;
}

RegionsSingleImage::RegionsSingleImage(IplImage *I)
{
  assert(I != NULL);
  im = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(I), I->depth, I->nChannels);
  cvCopy(I, im, 0);
  list = new std::vector<Region *>;
}

RegionsSingleImage::~RegionsSingleImage()
{
  if(list)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i< list->size(); i++)
      if(list->at(i))
    delete(list->at(i)); 
  delete(list);
  cvReleaseImage(&im);
}
```

I need to make my destructor virtual as it deals with abstract objects however I'm not sure where I can put the 'virtual' keyword or how to organize the code based on the layout. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `virtual` keyword needs to go on the *declaration* (usually in the .hpp file), not the *definition* (usually in the .cpp file except for inline or template functions)

Answer (score 1):

You put the `virtual` keyword in the header declaration `"RegionsSingleImage.hpp"`.

Comment: "You can then also mark the definition with virtual in the .cpp file", no

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, I was blatantly wrong, I was thinking about the declaration in the derived class actually. Thanks, removed.

Comment: Ah thank you. So doing that stopped the warnings from the destructor being called from another file, however, I'm still getting an error: RegionsSingleImage.cpp:38:5: warning: delete called on 'Region' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
delete(list->at(i))

Comment: Any idea what could be the cause? Thanks!

Comment: @DannyFitzpatrick If `Region` is an abstract class, therefore it has (pure) virtual functions, make sure it has a virtual destructor, something as simple as `virtual ~Region() = default;` will do. Otherwise you get into trouble when trying to delete derived objects via a pointer to `Region` (in fact, you have undefined behaviour, which is one of the worst things). As a general rule, every class that contains virtual functions and which may be used in a hierarchy via pointers needs to have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @DannyFitzpatrick Make sure you compile with C++11 enabled (`-std=c++11` for gcc or clang). If your compiler doesn't support C++11, just use `virtual ~Region(){}` instead. And make absolutely sure that the class you're writing the destructor for is indeed called `Region`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare it as `virtual`, eg

```
class RegionSingleImage {
  ..
  virtual ~RegionSingleImage();
}
```

Mind that this must be done on the first object of the hierarchy for which you are going to store pointers around, and only for it since it will be implicitly virtual in any subclass (as with every `virtual` method).